# TypeError: step() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(311)
ax1.set_title('Sinyal 20 Hz dan 40 HZ Simusoids')
plt.plot(sinyal_gabungan)
plt.step(ax1.get_xticklabels())
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I resolve this issue /error ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that isn't your entire code so it would be best to put that there but also the step function has to have a y coordinate so maybe try 0 and see if it works.

Comment: The error message seems self-explanatory. Perhaps you could consult [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html) to see what arguments `step` is expecting. In any event, please post a [mcve].